# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java

Столкнулся с проблемой, не работает следующий java - код:

```
String s_date = " Ср, 16 12 2015 16:24:31 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "     dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss    " );
Date date = sdf.parse( s_date );
System.out.println( sdf.format( date ) );
```

Выкидывает:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: " Ср, 16 12 2015 16:24:31 GMT"
```

Можно конечно обрезать первые пять символов и последние четыре. Но у меня будет много разных форматов дат, и для каждой разный подход. Как сделать чтобы SimpleDateFormat.parse(), парсил только то что указано?

Если в коде не видно, я в задании шаблона подставил 5 пробелов в начале и 4 в конце, это не помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конкретно в вашем случае надо править форматную строку:

```
    // было: "dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    // модификации: EEE - день недели строкой, HH - час 0-23, zzz - временная зона
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( " EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", new Locale("ru", "RU") );
    Date date = sdf.parse( s_date );
    System.out.println( sdf.format( date ) ); //Вывод:  Ср, 16 12 2015 19:24:31 MSK
```

Новое API:

```
    DateTimeFormatter newFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E, d M y H:m:s z", new Locale("ru", "RU") );
    ZonedDateTime newDate = ZonedDateTime.parse( s_date.trim(), newFormatter );
    System.out.println( newFormatter.format( newDate )); // Вывод: Ср, 16 12 2015 16:24:31 GMT
```

Comment: Спасибо, так вроде работает, правда при подборе рабочего шабблона теперь еще придется и локали подбирать (некоторые даты из моей подборки, записаны с указанием дней недели на английском языке)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, подойдёт использование регулярных выражений, выделяющих нужную часть даты из строки.

```
String s_date = " Ср, 16 12 2015 16:24:31 GMT";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s_date);

if (matcher.find()) {
    Date date = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(matcher.group(1));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
}
else {
    System.out.println("No match!");
}
```

Если же всё совсем плохо и формат даты может быть непредсказуем, то хорошим выбором может стать [natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/).

Comment: Я не силен в sed, (или что там в регулярных выражениях). Видимо надо занятся, жаль что в шаблоне нельзя указать неиспользуемые символы.

Comment: @DanielN. В шаблоне можно указать всё, что угодно.